# How to remove the space in front of the matched content that transfered to sink Vim FZF?

Tags: linux, vim, fzf

Fzf seems to automatically add spaces in front of the matched content, And then transfer it to sink.

```sh
let g:vimspector_json_path=$HOME . "/.config/vimspector_template/"
command! -bang -nargs=* LoadVimSpectorJson call fzf#run({
            \   'source': 'ls ' . vimspector_json_path,
            \   'sink': 'e .vimspector.json | 0r' . vimspector_json_path,
            \   'down': '25%',
            \   'options': '--preview-window=hidden'
            \ })
```

```
Vim(read):E484: Can't open file /home/lee/.config/vimspector_template/ python.json
```

Error because of the space before the filename `python.json` .

Is there any way to remove this space?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an additional user-command to load a template by name and do the directory concatenation in that command.

For example:

```
command! -bar -nargs=1 LoadVimSpectorTemplate
    \ execute "0r ".g:vimspector_json_path.<q-args>
```

So `:LoadVimSpectorTemplate python.json` will load that template file from the vimspector template directory.

In your `fzf#run()` call, you can then use:

```
'sink': 'e .vimspector.json | LoadVimSpectorTemplate'
```